# Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/StreamListener

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to stream Twitter data into spark streaming. I have exported additional jars using following command -

```
spark-shell --jars twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar,spark-streaming-twitter_2.11-1.6.2.jar
```

But at time of `ssc.start()` , getting following error -

```
scala> ssc.start()
```

> Exception in thread "streaming-start" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   twitter4j/StreamListener
>   at org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterInputDStream.getReceiver(TwitterInputDStream.scala:55)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$$anonfun$8.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:415)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$$anonfun$8.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:414)
>
> at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>
> at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>
> at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>
> at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
>
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.launchReceivers(ReceiverTracker.scala:414)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker.start(ReceiverTracker.scala:157)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.start(JobScheduler.scala:82)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamingContext.scala:610)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:606)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$$anonfun$liftedTree1$1$1.apply(StreamingContext.scala:606)
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$$anon$1.run(ThreadUtils.scala:122)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.StreamListener
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>
> ... 16 more
>
> 18/03/29 16:20:55 INFO StreamingContext: StreamingContext started

I am code given in following link-

https://acadgild.com/blog/streaming-twitter-data-using-spark/

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a missing dependency , that you need to add

please try to add this jar as a dependency , it has the class that you need

**twitter4j.StreamListener**

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-stream/4.0.7
```

You will need to find the jar version which is build for your spark version and scala/java/python version